# How to properly call fetch() on NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm in the process of learning about CoreData. I've been going through [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial) but have run into a compilation issue in one of my `UIViewController`s methods. Unless I am making an obvious mistake that is exactly what the code in the tutorial does. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1.

```
func getStores() {
    guard let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Store")

    do {
      // Compilation error on the next line:
      // Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<Store>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
      stores = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch  {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

Earlier in my VC I declared the `stores` array using the wrong CoreData Entity. Fixing that mistake solved the problem.

Comment: If `stores` is defined with the type `[Store]` then you might be getting a mismatch with the call to `fetch` which in your case I believe has the type `[NSManagedObject]` - what is the actual error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changed line**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Store")
```

**To Either:**

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Store.fetchRequest()
```

**Or**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Store>(entityName: "Store")
```

Comment: Weird. Even using either of those changes I still get the same error ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/ABMAeVYIpdxGc66qj7CXMZ53y8c8pxTdLKUB/image.png)

Comment: @RobertJoseph Try to clean build the project because this is working perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried that. I even went as far as deleting the project from my DerivedData folder. Something odd is going on. Thanks for the help. I'll mark this as solved because I'm certain you are correct.

Comment: @RobertJoseph Welcome mate :)